# How to find holomorphic function $f=u+iv$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is $u(x,y) = e^x siny$ with $f(0)=0$. I should find out if the function is harmonic and to find holomorphic function.

I showed that function is harmonic with the rule: $\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$

How do I find holomorphic function $f=u+iv$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

use Euler's relation, $e^{iy} = \cos y + i\sin y $.  You can apply this so that $u +iv$ is an exponential.  (Or in particular, $-ie^{iy} = \sin y - i \cos y$ should make it apparent what to do).

What this question is targeting is the relationship between harmonic and holomorphic.  The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic (attack with Cauchy-Riemann to see this) and conversely any harmonic function is locally the real (or imaginary) part of some holomorphic function.  But when the harmonic function in question is nicely behaved, like here, you can lift it to a function that is globally holomorphic and well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use the Cauchy–Riemann equations:
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = e^x \cos y
,\qquad
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^x \sin y
$$
The first one gives $v(x,y)= e^x \cos y + g(y)$, which you plug into the second one to find $g$.